# force android to start rendering from the right

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

android likes to render layouts starting from the left. And so if there is not enough space, the rightmost views suffer. Is there a way to get android to start rendering from the right?

For my particular illustration, I am using sliding menus. So I have a left menu and a right menu. On initial launch the left menu displays and the left edge of the right menu displays. But then, when the user slides, I want the right-edge of the left menu to display, while the entire right menu displays. I can seem to get that.

Here is what I actually get: When user slides, left edge of the left menu displays. This seems to be because android always starts rendering a view from the left.

Comment: `android likes to render layouts starting from the left`. It doesn't `like` to do anything.  You should first understand the difference between layout and rendering and then understand how the measure and layout passes work.  How the layout is done is entirely deterministic and controllable.  For example, using a `RelativeLayout`, declaring the right most element first, then using `layout_toLeftOf` will cause measurement and layout to progress from right to left since the XML layout is processed top down in both passes.  Rendering is then irrelevant since layout is now done.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set layout_gravity="right" on the parent view.  It will align on the right then.

Comment: Post your entire layout code.  The other thing to do-  don't use linear layouts.  If you MUST have something align right, use a relative and align the rightmost elements to the parent's edge, then align the left elements relative to those right elements.

Comment: Actually I use `android:gravity="right"` and that works. Thank you so so much for understanding my question so well.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the bit about RelativeLayout. I needed that as well. Thanks.